# How to assign value of a git command to a variable using script

Tags: git, msysgit

Is it possible to assign the value a git command like `git rev-list -n 1 --before=<timestamp> master` to a variable.

Ex: `commits = git rev-list -n 1 --before=<timestamp> master`

then I want to something like

```
git tag RELEASE_01 $commits[0]
```

My repository is on a windows XP system and I'm using msysgit.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use backticks or `$()` to evaluate one command within another, for instance:

```
git tag RELEASE_01 `git rev-list -n 1 --before=<timestamp> master`
```

Comment: Using `$(<command>)` is a nice habit to get into, so when you find yourself needing to nest, you don't have to go back and change the front backtick.